# Assigning values to a variable in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
 currDate VARCHAR2(4000);
SELECT to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  into currDate
FROM DUAL;
```

on executing the above statements in oracle following error is coming

**ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"**

Kindly help me in resolving it.
Thank you

Comment: What are you going to do with `currDate` after you've set it, and from which client? That will determine if you can use a substitution variable, a bind variable, or if it should just be in a PL/SQL block. Converting a date to a string for anything except display is usually not a good idea anyway though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the value in a variable use something like below

```
variable currDate varchar2(100);

exec :currDate:=to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
select :currDate from dual;

:CURRDATE
---------- 
13/05/2014
```

Or you can use anonymous pl/sql block to do this

```
set serveroutput on

declare
 currDate varchar2(100);
begin
 SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') into currDate FROM DUAL;
 dbms_output.put_line(currDate);
end;

/
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't work; `:currDate` is still null afterwards. You should also be using `to_char` not `to_date` in both examples.

Comment: With your first example, do `print currDate` or `select :currDate from dual`; it is null. You're getting the date displayed from the query, in SQL*Plus at least, but the `into` clause isn't doing anything. (And the select errors in SQL Developer 4, with ORA-01006, for some reason).

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the explanation. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. it is working now. But i wan't to know why is my code not working, because what I have written is the general syntax for assigning values to variables through select statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between SQL and PL/SQL( procedural extension of SQL). 
What you have written is the syntax for pl/sql block. General form of [PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS001) block is

```
declare
...
begin
/* your code */
exception
....
end;
/
```

If you need to assign value to a variable, the general syntax in SQL is

declaring a variable `variable currDate varchar2(100);`

assinging value to variable `exec :currDate:=to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY');`

This variable `:currDate` is global and it can be used throughout the session.